# Meteor application hangs up after creating bundle

Tags: node.js, meteor

I am trying to run meteor app after deploying but it hangs up and never responds I have already set all the env varibales. Please help

```
node main.js
```

Note: you are using a pure-JavaScript implementation of bcrypt.
While this implementation will work correctly, it is known to be
approximately three times slower than the native implementation.
In order to use the native implementation instead, run

meteor npm install --save bcrypt

in the root directory of your application.

... no response

Comment: what env variables are you setting? Does the app actually work in development?

Comment: yes it works fine in dev,

Comment: env varibles are the standard one root url and mongo url

Comment: Are you using any npm modules? After you built the bundle, can you try to navigate to ```/bundle/program/server```  and do an ```npm install``` and the try to run the app?

Comment: Yes I did everything, I am trying almost everything on google but it failing.. still